# Why am I getting client.getVersion is not a function with Braintree? (Braintree-Web)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, paypal, payment, braintree

I am trying to render the hostedFields from Braintree. What is happening is I create a key and get my token, I pass that too my function to create the hostedFields but then I get an error `client.getVersion is not a function`. I am certain that my client token im passing is correct and I know the SDK versions match.

What else am I missing thats causing this error and the fields not to match? Can you notice something from the code below?

````
import { client, hostedFields } from 'braintree-web';
import styles from '../../styles/Booking.module.css';

export default function PaymentForm() {

    const createClient = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await client.create({
                authorization: '<MY_SANDBOX_KEY>'
             });
             const clientToken = res._configuration.authorization;
             clientDidCreate(clientToken)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

    }

    const clientDidCreate = (client) => {
       console.log(client);
        hostedFields.create({
            client: client,
            styles: {
                'input': {
                    'font-size': '16pt',
                    'color': '#3A3A3A'
                  },
                  '.number': {
                    'font-family': 'monospace'
                  },
                  '.valid': {
                    'color': 'green'
                  }
            },
            fields: {
                number: {
                    container: '#card-number'
                },
                cvv: {
                    container: '#cvv',
                    placeholder: '***'
                },
                expirationDate: {
                    container: '#expiration-date'
                }
            }
        }) 

        console.log(res);
    }


    useEffect(() => {   
     createClient()
    }, []);
  
    return (
            <form>
                <label htmlFor="card-number">Card Number</label>
                <div id="card-number"></div>
                <label htmlFor="cvv">CVV</label>
                <div id="cvv"></div>
                <label htmlFor="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
                <div id="expiration-date"></div>
                <p>By submitting this order, I agree to the <a href="#">Treatment Program Terms</a> and <a href="#"> Privacy Notice.</a></p>
                <button  type="button">Submit </button>
            </form>
       
    )
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

In hostedFields.create, the client should be replaced with authorization option

```js
hostedFields.create({
  authorization: client,
  styles: {
    'input': {
      'font-size': '16pt',
      'color': '#3A3A3A'
    },
    '.number': {
      'font-family': 'monospace'
    },
    '.valid': {
      'color': 'green'
    }
  },
  fields: {
    number: {
      container: '#card-number'
    },
    cvv: {
      container: '#cvv',
      placeholder: '***'
    },
    expirationDate: {
      container: '#expiration-date'
    }
  }
}) 

console.log(res);
```